# Error: "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" in MySql, using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a row in MySQL, using PHP.

This is what my MySql request lookslike:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `ordre` SET `navne`='[value-1]',`adresse`='[value-2]',`postnummer`='[value-3]',`city`='[value-4]',`phone`='[value-5]',`email`='[value-6]',`note`='[value-7]',`modtag_nyhedsbrev`='[value-8]',`fragt_metode`='[value-9]',`betalings_metode`='[value-10]',`samlet_pris`='[value-11]',`ordre_modtaget`='$_POST[ordre_recieved]',`betalt`='$_POST[payment_recieved]',`afsendt`='$_POST[ordre_afsendt]',`ordrenr`='[value-15]',`ordredato`='[value-16]',`cartInfoNameID`='[value-17]',`cartInfoProductVal`='[value-18]',`cartInfoSubTotal`='[value-19]',`paypalGebyr`='[value-20]',`http_user_agent`='[value-21]',`ip_logger`='[value-22]' WHERE ordrenr = $_id";
```

But every single time I tries to update, it gives me this error:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'.

This is what my PHPMyAdmin setup lookslike:

```
CREATE TABLE `ordre` (
  `navne` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `adresse` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `postnummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(502) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `modtag_nyhedsbrev` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fragt_metode` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `betalings_metode` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `samlet_pris` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ordre_modtaget` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `betalt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `afsendt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ordrenr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ordredato` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cartInfoNameID` longtext COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cartInfoProductVal` longtext COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cartInfoSubTotal` longtext COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `paypalGebyr` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `http_user_agent` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip_logger` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ordrenr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=519 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/scsLj.jpg

Comment: try removing ,`ordrenr`='[]', from the query.

Comment: Would not recommend running that query without a `WHERE` in your SQL tho

Comment: Sorry, it should be: 'ordrenr'='[value-15]' :)

Comment: please refer to @DarkBee's comment.

Comment: I've updated the description of my question, with my new code. But it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Please, instead of an illegible screenshot, post the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead.

Comment: Updated my question again, with the SHOW CREATE TABLE values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordrenr` is your primary key and also `AUTO_INCREMENT`. This should give you trouble. Remove this column update from the query:

```
`ordrenr` = '[]',
```

Comment: Ooh, now I understand what you mean. Thank you, it works now. However, it gives me [value-x] as inserted value, instead of the old current value. Shouldn't [value-x] give me the current value, or did I misunderstood completely?

Comment: Only add the fields to the query that are actualy changed. If u dont include a field it will retain it's old value